# How to get the path from Route?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I've been trying to catch an undefined URL and pass it to my component which would handle it (display the message). I am not sure how to pass the current URL that has been caught. Thank you.

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path='*' render={() => <HttpError data={"Undefined URL: " + this.props.match}/>}/>
</Switch>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the route props to the component being rendered. Access `props.match.url` to get the URL of the route being rendered.

```
<Switch>
  <Route
    exact
    path='*'
    render={(routeProps) => (
      <HttpError data={"Undefined URL: " + routeProps.match.url} />
    )}
  />
</Switch>
```

If you are using this as a sort of "404" route then you can place it last in your `Switch`, remove the `exact` prop (*you can remove the `path` prop too*) and if nothing before it matches then this will be returned/rendered by the `Switch`.

```
<Switch>
  // ... all other routes
  <Route
    render={(routeProps) => (
      <HttpError data={"Undefined URL: " + routeProps.match.url} />
    )}
  />
</Switch>
```